# Magento Adminhtml createblock() Form 'Mage_Core_Exception' Ivalid Block Type

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, blocks, create

I want to create my own admin site.

config.xml :

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mymodule_Test>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mymodule_Test>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <test>
                <class>Mymodule_Test_Helper</class>
            </test>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <mymoduletest>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                   <module>Mymodule_Test</module>
                   <frontName>mymoduletest</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymoduletest>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <test>
                    <file>test.xml</file>
                </test>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

adminhtml.xml:

```
<menu>
    <test translate="title" module="test">
        <title>Test</title>
        <sort_order>300</sort_order>
        <children>
            <!-- child items go here -->
            <show translate="title" module="test">
                <title>SubTest</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <action>mymoduletest/adminhtml_show</action>
            </show>
        </children>
    </test>
</menu>
```

controllers\Adminhtml\ShowController.php :

```
<?php Class Mymodule_Test_Adminhtml_ShowController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

protected function _initAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('test/show');
    return $this;
}

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_initAction()
         ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mymodule_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Show'))
         ->renderLayout();
}}
```

Block\Adminhtml\Show.php :

```
<?php class Mymodule_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Show extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container{

public function __construct()
{

    parent::__construct();

    $this->removeButton('back');
    $this->removeButton('reset');
    $this->removeButton('delete');
    $this->removeButton('add');
    $this->removeButton('save');
    $this->removeButton('edit');

    $this->setId('testContainer');

    $this->_blockGroup = 'test';
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml';
    $this->_mode = 'show';

    $this->_headerText  = 'TEST';
}}
```

My admin page shows the headText byt ow I get this exception:

> exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'invalid block type:
>   Mage_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Show_Form' in
>   /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php:595

And on my admin page this:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean in
>   /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php
>   on line 129

Why magento creates the block: **Mage_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Show_Form** and not **Mymodule_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Show_Form** ???

The Block\Adminhtml\Show\Form.php :

```
<?php class Mymodule_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Show_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->setId('showGeneralForm');
    $this->setTemplate('test/show.phtml');
}

protected function _beforeToHtml()
{
    return parent::_beforeToHtml();
}}
```

Comment: please include all of your etc/config.xml file.

Comment: Edit: add full config.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add following in your config.xml file in `<global>` tag

```
<blocks>
    <test>
      <class>Mymodule_Test_Block</class>
   </test>
</blocks>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be like this:

in your config.xml

```
<config>
.....
    <global>
       .......
       <blocks>
            <test>
               <class>Mymodule_Test_Block</class>
            </test>
       </blocks>
      .......
    </global>
.....
</config>
```

and in your controller

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_initAction()
         ->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('test/adminhtml_show'))
         ->renderLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On your `config.xml` file  your do not define class

But you have call the block class on at `Mymodule_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Show` at `ShowController.php`

As per as magento system,you **cannot use direct class**  name on **createBlok** function.

Need call the block class by block type

**So, need to define block type at xml**

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <test> <-- module block identifire -->
                <class>Mymodule_Test_Block</class>
            </test>
        </blocks>

        <helpers>
    ...
```

As you  want to call class `Mymodule_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Show`  then

it block type should be `'test/adminhtml_show'`

**As per as magento system**

- `test => Mymodule_Test_Block`
- `adminhtml_show =>Adminhtml_Show`

`$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mymodule_Test_Block_Adminhtml_Show')`

**change to**

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('test/adminhtml_show')
```